# Visual Studio Control Recognition

Tags: visual-studio-2012, webforms, variable-assignment, auto-generate

The original problem:

I would add a control in a .aspx web form file, save it, and the designer code would not be appropriately updated. Therefore, my code behind file could not find any of the variables I was telling it about.

Things I tried to do that didn't work:

Converting the aspx file to web form. Storing the text inside, but deleting the files in the solution and re-adding them, re-adding code. Closing and opening VS.

Thing I tried that did work:

Deleting the files in the solution and re-adding them. Readded text bit by bit.

Emperical cause of the problem was in code behind aspx.cs file:
        private const string RECORDSPERPAGE = "RecordsPerPage";

At any point in time after the addition of this variable (seen in this block)...

public partial class RequestSearch : ProtectedPage
    {
        private const string TOTALPAGES = "TotalPages";
        private const string CURRENTPAGEINDEX = "CurrentPageIndex";
        private const string RECORDSPERPAGE = "RecordsPerPage";

...if a control was added in the aspx file, the designer code was not updated appropriately and the code behind could not recognize the subsequently added controls, which were similar to this one...

I changed the name of this string constant to RESULTSPERPAGE. Everything worked after that.

So my problem is solved, it seems, but I have no idea why. RECORDSPERPAGE is not declared anywhere but that file, not used anywhere but in an analogous way to the other private string constants shown that do not cause the designer generation problem.

Hoping someone will have knowledge of the magic of Visual Studio that is allowing this kind of behavior, or alert me to somewhere else I might look to understand better the underlying cause of the problem.